# Running batch file with powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to run a batch file from my powershell script. When I push the button Office it should go to the batch file from Office.
The following is in the powershell:

```
function Office {
 $Office="install\Office 2019\Click To Run.bat"
. "$office"
}
```

The batch file contains:

```
setup /configure of2019stndmks.xml
```

When I run my powershell script and try the above it returns:
'Setup' is not recognized as an internal or external commmand, operable program or batch file.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try changing your bat-line to `%~dp0setup.exe /configure of2019stndmks.xml` and see if that does the trick. That's assuming that setup.exe is in the same folder as `Click To Run.bat`. You could also skip the .bat-file altogether.

Comment: I would recommend `"%~dp0setup.exe"`, and probably using the `start` command too, however, if that's all you have in the [tag:batch-file], why run one at all, just run `setup` directly from [tag:powershell].

Comment: How would I run the setup directly from powershell with the XML file so it configures well.